# Displaying dynamic content based on browser location

Tags: php

I had an idea of writing a page template in my `index.php` where the content section of the page will include the content dynamically by determining what url the browser is at and getting the content page based on that. There's a few issues though:

```
<?php
// /index.php

?>
<!-- html tags and menu/layout divs as needed go here -->

<section id="content">
<?php 
    function curPageURL()
    {
        $page = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1); 
        return $page;
    }

    $page = curPageURL();
        switch ($page)
        {
            case "index.php":
                include_once("includes/home.php");
                break;
        }
?>
</section>

<!-- footer and such goes here -->
```

Although this works, I'm having trouble applying the concept further. I just can't seem to get my head around how the navigation should work or how to apply this concept to other pages in my site...

If anyone can advise, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: have you tried doing it in htaccess; i think you are reinventing the wheel when this is usually done in the apache level

Comment: You should try using a lightweight PHP framework. It will save you from having to write your own mini MVC and is likely to be more secure also. Take a look at CodeIgniter and Kohana.

Comment: @relentless it was just an idea I had. I didn't want to end p rewriting code like I normally do. Any workable alternatives you can suggest would probably be more helpful than asking why I'm doing something...

Comment: Asking why you're doing something might help me and others understand your true goal and therefore recommend a different solution. Chill out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `.htaccess` file (put in the same directory as index.php).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And then in index.php you can get the page with:

```
$page = $_GET['uri'];
```

So if you user goes to `example.com/home` then the page variable will be set to `home`.

Comment: Potential for a security vulnerability of local/remote file inclusion, depending on how this is implemented. Keep that in mind and be sure you're educated when using this technique so that you don't create a security vulnerability in your site.